# Solving PDE $xu_x+(x+t)u_t=1$ with $u(1,t)=t$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics, transport-equation

> Solve $xu_x+(x+t)u_t=1$ such that $u(1,t)=t$.
>
> Is the solution defined everywhere?

I had known that this specific problem is related to a Heat Equation problem. I tried solving for its characteristic curves but I had difficulty solving for its parametrized initial condition.

How am I gonna solve for its parametrized initial condition? I know that for an initial condition $u(x,0)$,

$x(0,s)=s$

$y(0,s)=0$

Comment: How is it related to the heat equation?

Comment: What are $x$ and $y$ in your question?

Answer (score 0):

The Method. Set $\mathbf x = (x,t)$. Your PDE is
$$ \mathbf a \cdot \nabla u= b$$
where $\mathbf a(x,t) = (x,x+t), b\equiv 1. $
The initial data is prescribed along the curve $\mathbf x_0(z) =(1,z)$, which is
$$ u(\mathbf x_0(z)) =  u_0(z)$$where $u_0(z) = z$.
Note that $\mathbf x_0'(z)^\perp \cdot \mathbf a(\mathbf x_0(z)) =(-1,0)\cdot (1,1+z) = -1  $ so there are no characteristic points.
If you first solve the 2 ODEs
$$ \partial_s\mathbf X(z,s) = \mathbf a(\mathbf X(z,s)),\quad \mathbf X(z,0) =  \mathbf x_0(z), \\
 \partial_s  Y(z,s) = b,\quad\qquad\ \ \ \ \  Y(z,0) = u_0(z),$$
then you can check that the solution $u=u(\mathbf x)$ to the original problem is given by
$$ u(\mathbf X(z,s)) = Y(z,s).$$
Obtaining the form of $u(\mathbf x)$ naturally involves inverting the formula for $\mathbf X$.

Implementation.
$$Y(z,s)=z+s.\\\left.\substack{\displaystyle \partial_sX_1 =X_1\qquad \\ \displaystyle\partial_sX_2 =X_1+X_2   }\right\}\implies \mathbf X(z,s) = \binom{e^s}{(z+s)e^s}.
$$
Inverting $\mathbf X$:
$$ s = \log x,\qquad \\z = t/x-\log x.$$
So $\mathbf X^{-1}(x,t) = (\log x, t/x-\log x).$
This gives the solution $u(x,t) = t/x$.